# remove empty post elements

Tags: php, post

I am getting an array in POST having 2 fields and based upon first field fetching the matched data from mysql table to display, it works fine till here.
but second fields in array may be empty and I do not want to display them here is my code.

```
<p class="yorder">
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $exp_key = substr($key, 0, 1);
        if($exp_key[0] == 'p'){
            if($i % 2 != 0){
                $tprod = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE prodname = '". $tprod ."'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            ?>
            <span class="o1">&nbsp;</span>
            <span class="o2"><?php echo $value; ?></span>
            <?php } if($i % 2 != 0){ $i++; continue;} ?>
            <span class="o3"><?php echo $value; ?></span>
            <span class="o4"><?php echo $value * $row['price']; ?></span>

        <?php $i++;}
    }
?>

</p>
```

here is the screen shot of my result
[image]
thanks

my logic is : first I check 1st array item with database and get its value, then I continue the loop and get the 2nd array item and display it.

What I am trying to do now  is: I am getting this array in POST 
Array ( [prodname0] => Chicken Sandwich [port-0] => [prodname1] => Roasted Chicken Sandwich [port-1] => 2 [prodname2] => Tanu's Special Chicken Sandwich [port-2] => 2 [prodname3] => Cheese Sandwich [port-3] => [prodname4] => Chicken Salami Sandwich [port-4] => [prodname5] => Chicken Ham Sandwich [port-5] => [prodname6] => Egg and Mayoinnaise Sandwich [port-6] => [prodname7] => Bhetki Fry [port-7] => [prodname8] => Pao Bhaji [port-8] => [prodname9] => Puffs [port-9] => [prodname10] => Chicken Cutlet [port-10] => [prodname11] => Mutton Chop [port-11] => [prodname12] => Egg Devil [port-12] => [prodname13] => Paneer Cutlet [port-13] => )

Can I change it to like : Chicken Sandwich => Roasted Chicken Sandwich => 2
this will do my job I think

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to do this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if(empty($value){
        continue;
    }

    // Other code

}
```

First check if the POST value is empty and if it is, use the `continue` keyword to skip the rest of the code in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your php code with this

```
<?php
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $exp_key = substr($key, 0, 1);
            if(!empty($key) || !empty($value)){   //edited portion
             if($exp_key[0] == 'p'){
                if($i % 2 != 0){
                    $tprod = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE prodname = '". $tprod ."'";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                ?>
                <span class="o1">&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="o2"><?php echo $value; ?></span>
                <?php } if($i % 2 != 0){ $i++; continue;} ?>
                <span class="o3"><?php echo $value; ?></span>
                <span class="o4"><?php echo $value * $row['price']; ?></span>

            <?php $i++;}
          }
        }  //edited portion
    ?>
```